# How can I stop downloading but continue seeding with BitTorrent on Android?

Tags: android-12, google-pixel-6, bittorrent

I wonder the following: How can I stop downloading but continue seeding with [BitTorrent on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.client&hl=en_US&gl=US)? I use Pixel 6 + Android 12.

Comment: Does this app not offer speed controls per torrent or app-wide? If it does, set download  speed to 1KB/s.

Comment: @Firelord thanks, only app-wide, but I need to download other torrents.

Comment: You should probably mention/link to which bittorrent client you are using and given that there are other clients look for one with your needs.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I use BitTorrent on Android https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.client&hl=en_US&gl=US